# The meaning of ARGFRAME and LOCFRAME in AVR Assembly

Tags: assembly, avr, iar

In an effort to debug a problem in some C code I wrote, I am examining a some assembly code generated by the IAR AVR compiler. At the top of the .s90 file there are several functions declared. Each function delcaration has the following form:

```
PUBLIC FunctionName1
FUNCTION FunctionName1,021201H
ARGFRAME CSTACK, 0, STACK
LOCFRAME RSTACK, 2, STACK
```

Does anyone know what the ARGFRAME AND LOCFRAME directives do? They are only briefly mentioned in the IAR EWAVR Assembler Reference. Sometimes I see the functions declared using RSTACK as a parameter of ARGFRAME instead of CSTACK:

```
PUBLIC FunctionName2
FUNCTION FunctionName2,021201H
ARGFRAME RSTACK, 0, STACK
LOCFRAME RSTACK, 2, STACK
```

Anyone know the reasoning behind using RSTACK vs CSTACK with ARGFRAME?

Answer (score 1):

As I'm sure you know already, `CSTACK` is generally used as the parameter stack, and `RSTACK` in the return address stack.  In the case you've outlined above, there are no parameters.  So it's safe to use `RSTACK` in the directive, since it isn't actually going to store anything there.

As far as what they actually do, it seems like they help reserve space in the correct locations.  `ARGFRAME` and `LOCFRAME` can point to stack locations, or static areas if the function doesn't need to be reentrant.  It seems like an abstraction about how that's done exactly.  It's been a long time since I've used IAR's AVR compiler... I don't remember having this facility 10 years ago, so I'm sorry I can't help more on that front.